# dynamically created button is only appearing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am tring to create the update status box like facebook using Javascript/jQuery.
When i click on post button the div element is created but the button that i have appended inside it is appearing only once.

This is my script code:

```
var hello = function() {
    var post = $.trim($("#status_message").val());

    if (post.length != 0) {
        $('<div id="hi">').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $("#status_message").val(" ");
        $("#hi").append($("#delete"));
        $("#hi").append($("#comment"));    
    }

}
```

html code:

```
<input type="button" id="post" name="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="hello()">  
<div class="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Side note, This will generate duplicate IDs - **Invalid HTML**.

Comment: What does `only appears once` mean? .Also you can't repeat ID's in a page, use classes

Comment: only appears once means button appears only for the first div created dynamically and thats it.

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to dynamically create a div element that has text from the status box and also delete and comment buttons

Comment: This is not a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (mcve), there are multiple id's in the JS that are not in the HTML. Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so users can see the error

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question that is linked to. It has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `.append($('#delete'));` You are simply moving an existing div called `$('#delete')` and appending it to the `#hi` element. So only one will be used...

However, some of the stuff you are doing doesn't make any sense anyways... You shouldn't use `id` if you are going to have more than one of them as a rule of thumb. If you have multiple elements with the same name you should have them identified as a part of a class and use the class attribute. If there is only one element then you should use id.

You would want to do something like this...

```js
function hello() {
    var post = "test";
    var content = $('<div class="hi">');
    content.text(post)
        .append($('<div class="delete">delete</div>'))
        .append($('<div class="comment">comment</div>'))
        .prependTo('.posts');
}
```

Comment: Hey that worked! I got the error that I had in my code. Thank you very much

Comment: If I have to delete just one ".hi" div.    
$("#delete").click(function()
{
$(this).remove();
});   is what comes in my mind. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: If you want to delete one using the delete class you would add an onclick to the delete and then do something along `$(this).closest('.hi').remove();` to remove the element.